# django testing: client.get returns MultipleObjectsReturned error

Tags: django, django-testing

When I run the following test, I want client.get() to return a list of examples. It does so correctly, but it throws this error:

`MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Example -- it returned 8!`

How do I deactivate this error?

```
def test_read_all_examples(self):
        # get all examples
        url = reverse('example')

        admin = User.objects.get(username='admin')
        client = APIClient()
        client.force_authenticate(user=admin)

        response = client.get(url, format='json')
        print("GET - ExampleTests Response:", response.data)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you got this problem, but the `get` call threw the exception was `User.objects.get` not `client.get`.  I would check your database tables for multiple accounts with the `username` of `admin`.

---

Adding:  it’s typically calls to `ModelManager.get` that throw `DoesNotExist` and `MultipleObjectsReturned`.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/exceptions/

Comment: I finally found the error: it was on a different test. Sorry for wasting your time.